# Is logical equivalence itself a proposition?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I understand that the biconditional $P \leftrightarrow Q$ is a hypothesis that may be true or false depending on the truth values of P and Q.

Furthermore, I understand that the logical equivalence $P \Leftrightarrow Q$ is the assertion that the biconditional is a tautology, i.e. that the hypothesis is true.

However, isn't $P \Leftrightarrow Q$ itself a proposition? After all, it is equivalent to the statement that $P \leftrightarrow Q$ is tautologically equivalent to $T:$ $$(P \Leftrightarrow Q) \Leftrightarrow ((P \leftrightarrow Q) \Leftrightarrow T).$$ Is this a circular? Or is there some "higher form" of equality that logical equivalence lives in?

Comment: Indeed if you poke at the seams of logic you inevitably run into such a circular dynamic. Usually this is "avoided" by defining things like a metalanguage and the like. But make no mistake, sometimes a recursive definition can be quite stable and still useful for proving things.

Comment: Note that if $P$ and $Q$ are atomic propositions, then $(P↔Q)$ cannot be a tautology. Furthermore, note that a tautology (for example, a logical equivalence) isn't merely a true sentence but a *logically* true sentence.

Answer (score 4):

It is an equivalence in a metalanguage, which loosely speaking is a "higher form" of equality. Basically saying that $P\Leftrightarrow Q$ says that "$P$ is true if and only if $Q$ is true", where being true is something derivable from the rules of propositional logic. This is different from saying "$P\leftrightarrow Q$ is true", since the latter is a statement in propositional logic, whereas the former is a statement *about* propositional logic.

Read about metalanguages on the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalanguage).

Comment: This is great, thanks.