# Why logical equivalence sentences aren't considered as propositions?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In the book *Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications (by Kenneth H. Rosen)*, he defines logical equivalence as such

> "The compound propositions $p$ and $q$ are called logically equivalent if $p\leftrightarrow q$ is a tautology, The notation $p\equiv q$ denotes that $p$ and $q$ are logically equivalent"

Then he said that "$p \equiv q$" is not a compound proposition but rather is the statement that $p \leftrightarrow q$ is a tautology. By definition of a proposition or a statement (a declarative sentence that is either true or false, but not both), I feel like $p \equiv q$ can actually have a truth value. If $p$ isn't equivalent to $q$, then saying $p \equiv q$ would be false. So, what's making $p \equiv q$ not considered a (compound) proposition? I feel like $p \equiv q$ can be true or false. If it's a proposition, then does $p \equiv q$ also mean $(p \leftrightarrow q) \leftrightarrow T$, where $T$ is a tautology?

I'm aware that a quite similar question has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3777466/950283) but it doesn't really answer the first part of my question. Though from the answer there, it mentions something about metalanguage. Does that mean that I need to learn metalanguage to have my questions answered? Or am I just mistaken here? Thank you.

[image: Definition of logical equivalent and]

Comment: The *formal language* is made of propositional symbols: $p,q$ etc and *connectives*: $\lnot, \land, \to, \leftrightarrow$. *Compound* propositions are formulas of the language made of symbols and connectives (according to the rules of the langauge). *Tautology* and *logical equivalence* are concept of the meta-theory, i.e. regarding properties of formulas of the language. Thus, symbols, like $\vdash, \vDash, \equiv$ are **not** connectives (they do not belong to the language) but used in the meta- to express properties of formulas.

Comment: In conclusion, $\vDash \alpha$ is a shorthand for "formula $\alpha$ is a *tautology*" and $\alpha \equiv \beta$ is a shorthand for "formulas $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are *logical equivalent*".

Comment: Is "a sentence that declares a fact" literally the definition of the word *proposition* in this same book?

Comment: @DavidK sorry, that's actually for a "declarative sentence". I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by "proposition" you just mean a sentence that can be evaluated as true or false, then logical equivalences are propositions.
The difference he's getting at is that "$A \leftrightarrow B$" is a sentence of the object language (propositional logic), while "$A \leftrightarrow B$ is a tautology." is a sentence of the metalanguage (English), that speaks *about* the logical formula. In his terminology, the term "proposition" may be reserved for sentences of the object language. Hence his accentuating the fact that "$\equiv$" is not a logical connective, but rather short-hand for the English expression "is logically equivalent to".

Comment: So, he meant "$A \leftrightarrow B$ is a tautology" as in English sense? and I shouldn't take it as a part of the logical language?

Comment: also how do we know that "$A \leftrightarrow B$ is a tautology" is the language of metalanguage and not a proposition?

Comment: Propositions are only written in symbolic language with letters like $A$, $B$, etc. denoting propositions, and a fixed set of symbols like $\land, \lor$, etc. for connectives. They will not have English words like "is a tautology". Anything written with English words is in the metalanguage.

Comment: @Ted but if I let $A$ be the proposition "$P \equiv Q$ is a tautology", wouldn't that $A$ be a proposition?

Comment: When you say 'Let $A$ be the proposition "P $\equiv$ Q" is a tautology', you are already talking in the metalanguage. The object language only knows the *symbol* $A$, not what it stands for. You might think of the object language as consisting purely of strings of symbols, and the metalanguage as making statements about these strings.

Comment: @Ted I see... $A$ will then be a proposition but will "$P \equiv Q$ is a tautology" be a proposition too? If so, then why does the author of the book says that it is not a compound proposition? I understand what you said but I'm still a little confused.

Comment: I'm not sure what you take your atomic propositional formulas to be. Usually, they're $p, q, r, ...$ and so on. When I say something like "Let $A$ be the formula $p \land q$", then the "A" is not a part of the object language, but rather a variable on the level of the metalanguage. One could also claim: "For all logical formulas $A,B$: If $A \leftrightarrow B$ is a tautology, then $A \equiv B$." Here, also, $A$ and $B$ feature as variables used in the metalanguage rather than as atomic symbols of the object language.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of equivalence:
$$ (a \rightarrow b) \equiv (\lnot a \lor b), $$
where $a$ and $b$ are simple (not compound) propositions.
It's an equivalence because the compound proposition
$$ (a \rightarrow b) \leftrightarrow (\lnot a \lor b)  \tag1$$
is true for all four possible choices of the truth values of $a$ and $b$
where $a$ and $b$ independently can be either true or false,
that is, proposition $(1)$ is a tautology.

On the other hand, $a \rightarrow b$ and $a \lor b$ are **not** equivalent.
We can of course write
$$ (a \rightarrow b) \leftrightarrow (a \lor b),  \tag2$$
but this compound proposition won't be true for all possible values of $a$ and $b.$
For example, proposition $(2)$ is true when $a$ is false and $b$ is true,
but it is false when $a$ is true and $b$ is false.

We could write the compound proposition
$$ ((a \rightarrow b) \leftrightarrow (a \lor b)) \leftrightarrow T $$
where $T$ is a tautology, for example,
$$ ((a \rightarrow b) \leftrightarrow (a \lor b)) \leftrightarrow 
((a \rightarrow b) \leftrightarrow (\lnot a \lor b)). \tag3 $$

You could read proposition $(3)$ loosely as,
"Proposition $(2)$ is a tautology."
But what it really says is closer to,
"Proposition $(2)$ is true if and only if a tautology (specifically the tautology of proposition $(1)$) is true."

As it turns out, proposition $(3)$ is true whenever proposition $(2)$ is true, and false whenever proposition $(2)$ is false.
(Try checking it.)

What is missing from proposition $(3)$ is the qualification, "And this is true no matter which truth value (true or false) is assigned to each simple proposition independently of all other simple propositions."
That's what $p \equiv q$ gives you.
It says *no matter what else we suppose*, these two propositions are either both true or both false.

---

I think it's perfectly reasonable to object that $p \equiv q$ could be considered a proposition according to a definition that only requires a proposition to be a declarative sentence that is true or false.
That's a rather loose definition of a proposition;
we really ought to explain more concretely how simple propositions can be formed and how compound propositions can be formed.
It's also reasonable (given such a loose definition) to ask why
"$X$ is a tautology" is not a proposition when $X$ is a proposition.

The reasons for these apparent discrepancies (as I understand them)
is that propositional logic was never intended to be a universal language encompassing all possible true-or-false declarative sentences in English
(or if it was once hoped to be such a language, it was soon discovered that it cannot be).
Instead, we build up from very simple languages to more complex ones
(such as the metalanguages mentioned in comments).

Comment: I used to think that logic was the building blocks of mathematics and we start learning logic from propositional logic. Does this mean that propositional logic isn't really complete since it can't cover all possible true-or-false declarative sentences, making our mathematical understanding "incomplete"? Or are there other parts of logic that will make this "more" complete?

Comment: Mathematical understanding **is** incomplete and must remain so at some level -- see Gödel's Incompleteness Theorem. I think the point of propositional logic is to be a basic set of building blocks (not the complete set) for things we need to say in order to build the mathematics that we want to use, and that the way we use these building blocks is highly reliable, much more so than casual language. And yes, there are higher forms of logic that we need to employ while building mathematics, because propositions alone will only get you so far.